# ZF check if user is allowed on resources

Tags: zend-framework

I have set up an ACL with resources, roles and if access to resources allowed or not. The navigation is represented with icons. I want to show only the icons if the logged-in user is allowed to access the specific resource also. Will it be possible to detect wether a given user is allowed to access a given resources? Thank you in advance for any response ;)

Regards
Andrea

Comment: how have you defined your role ?

Comment: it can be done, i did a static function that checks if you have the rights by giving it the action, controller and user id, you should come something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Yes.

Medium answer:

It depends on how you set up you ACL. If your ACL is set up in the database, with resources, all you really have to do is check the user permissions for the particular link and if they are allowed to go there, show it.

To give more help, we would need to know how you have your ACL set up

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The ACL is not setuo in the database but have it as a class in my library...

Comment: Alright, well, if your resources are set up in a logical manner, you should be able to store the ACL in the registry after your done creating it. Then in the menu generation, pull it from the registry and check the menu items against the ACL